# Showing data in gridview on a specific cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a grid view in ASP.Net and its format is like this:

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | ...... |Col200
-----------------------------------
Row1 |      |      |        |      
-----------------------------------
Row2 |      |      |        |
-----------------------------------
Row3 |      |      |        |    
-----------------------------------
.
.
-----------------------------------
Row600|     |       |       |
```

Column named are in table1 and Row names are in table2. I made two separate data adapters & datasets one for column name and one for row name and bind the Gridview columns with Table1 and Gridview rows with Table2. The rest of the cells in GrdView are empty.

On empty cell I want to show some data which is in another table. How I can achieve this? Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve this by using row_created or row_databound ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grid view's `OnRowDataBound` event to intercept the data as it is being bound for each row in the grid and check the cell value to see if it is empty, like this:

Code-behind:

```
protected void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // Only work with data rows, ignore header and footer rows
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Check if value in cell is empty here
        // For example use the RowIndex property to check for row #2
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 2)
        {
            // Change text to X in cell 4
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "X";
        }


        // If so, then go to other table and retrieve value here

    }
}
```

Comment: But this function put data on all the rows . I want to add data on a specific cell. E.g if I want to write lets say "X" on Row2,Column4 What I have to do then.